# What factors should be used to choose `opcache.jit_buffer_size` value?

Tags: php, optimization, jit, php-8, opcache

I've been looking for some guidelines regarding the optimal value of `opcache.jit_buffer_size`. The proposed values are up to 256M (e.g. https://php.watch/versions/8.0/JIT#jit-opcache.jit_buffer_size) or even 500M (https://medium.com/@edouard.courty/make-your-php-8-apps-twice-as-fast-opcache-jit-8d3542276595). But it seems (to me) they're simply chosen just arbitrarily.

However, I couldn't find much explanation of how this value should be selected. The article "JIT in depth" (https://php.watch/articles/jit-in-depth#jit-ideal) gives a few clues.

The RFC https://wiki.php.net/rfc/jit does not help, either.

Is the answer "do some benchmarks in your environment and pick up the best buffer size"?

Comment: ...do you have an actual reason to want to change this value?

Comment: @dai The default value of `opcache.jit_buffer_size` is 0. In order to enable JIT, the buffer size must be > 0. So I'd like to know how I should select the appropriate non-zero value.

Comment: Ah, okay - I assumed there would be a sensible-default, weird.